# Querydsl and Feign - Multivalued Query Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, spring-cloud-feign

In my main application, I have a feign client that takes a searchCar of type `Car`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "car-service")
public interface CarClient {

@GetMapping("/car/search")
public Set<Car> findCars(@SpringQueryMap Car searchCar);

}
```

Car is a POJO:

```
class Car {
  int id;
  String model;
  String make;
}
```

In my Car Service application, I have a Spring REST controller that services the above feign client:

```
@RestController
public class CarController {
    
    @GetMapping("/car/search")
    public Iterable<Car> findCar(
            @QuerydslPredicate(root = Car.class) 
            Predicate predicate) {

        log.info("Find cars matching {}", predicate.toString());
        return carRepository.findAll(predicate);
    }
}
```

This works well except when I want the feign client to find cars in a list of ids, models, or makes. For example, the controller & my Querydsl config supports:

```
http://my-car-service/search/cars?make=Toyota&make=Honda
```

This will return all cars that have a make of Toyota or Honda.

How can feign client pass multiple ids, models and makes? Must I create another class such as:

```
class CarSearch {
  Set<Integer> id;
  Set<String> model;
  Set<String> make;
}
```

Or is there a way to create a QueryDsl `Predicate` for `Car` within my main application and have the feign client pass that instead of `Car`?